# Compile error - Dynamic SQL

Tags: sql-server, ssms, dynamic-sql

I've tried to implement some dynamic SQL to create a cursor as an extension of a simple SELECT query. The cursor is used as a way to print the GROUPED values returned from the SELECT as a message in SQL Server Management Studio (kind of like a visual summary of the data) . The purpose of this approach is half task related and half to benefit my understanding of how dynamic SQL can be developed. Code reads:

```
DECLARE @Focus VARCHAR(10);
SET @Focus = 'Completed'; /* User input event focus {Started, Completed} */
DECLARE @PeriodStartDate DATE, @PeriodEndDate DATE;
SET @PeriodStartDate = '04/01/2014';
SET @PeriodEndDate = GETDATE();
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX);
SET @sql = 
        'SELECT ' +
        'CASE DATEPART(M, ' + '[Event ' + CASE @Focus
                                                WHEN 'Started' THEN 'Start'
                                                WHEN 'Completed' THEN 'End'
                                                END + ' Date]) ' +
        ' WHEN 1 THEN ''January'' ' +
        ' WHEN 2 THEN ''February'' ' +
        ' WHEN 3 THEN ''March'' ' + 
        ' WHEN 4 THEN ''April'' ' +
        ' WHEN 5 THEN ''May'' ' +
        ' WHEN 6 THEN ''June'' ' +
        ' WHEN 7 THEN ''July'' ' +
        ' WHEN 8 THEN ''August'' ' +
        ' WHEN 9 THEN ''September'' ' +
        ' WHEN 10 THEN ''October'' ' +
        ' WHEN 11 THEN ''November'' ' +
        ' WHEN 12 THEN ''December'' ' +
        ' END AS [Event ' + @Focus + ' Month], ' +
        ' COUNT([Unique ID]) AS [Number of Events] ' +
        ' FROM [udf_Events](' + @Focus + ', ' + CAST(@PeriodStartDate AS VARCHAR) + ', ' + CAST(@PeriodEndDate AS VARCHAR) + ') ' +
        ' GROUP BY ' +
        ' DATEPART(M, ' + '[Event ' + CASE @Focus 
                                            WHEN 'Started' THEN 'Start' 
                                            WHEN 'Completed' THEN 'End'
                                            END + ' Date]) ' +
        ' ORDER BY ' +
        ' DATEPART(M, ' + '[Event ' + CASE @Focus
                                            WHEN 'Started' THEN 'Start'
                                            WHEN 'Completed' THEN 'End'
                                            END + ' Date]) '
;                                               
DECLARE Results CURSOR
FOR
    SELECT
        @sql;
```

The error message I receive:

> Msg 16924, Level 16, State 1, Line 71 Cursorfetch: The number of
>   variables declared in the INTO list must match that of selected
>   columns.

Through grappling with the problem and trying to execute the query as a SELECT statement (removing the complexity of the cursor) using EXEC(@sql) the error message reads:

> Invalid column name 'Completed'.

..Which leads me to believe the problem lies with the CASE expression in the first field selected. udf_Events is an in-line table valued function with three arguments. Amongst others, it has columns [Event Start Date] and [Event End Date] which are the values the cursor is looking to do its work on.

Comment: `Msg 16924, Level 16, State 1, Line 71 Cursorfetch` is not show in your code, `Completed` would probably read `[Event Completed Month]`, a simple PRINT @SQL should help to find the problem, so it's reading like a 'find my type' - question

Comment: The problem isn't with the CursorFetch, which is why the problem still occurs when the @sql is executed ignorant to any cursor being created. It wasn't necessary to post the cursor code as well.

Comment: In this case `Invalid column name 'Completed'` vs. PRINT @SQL is a find my typo question and would fit for OT 'a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical '

Comment: @bummi I think the issue is the dates in the call to `udf_Events` as they are not quoted. I think this _could_ be on topic for dynamic SQL as I would guess it's quite a common error?

Comment: Yes the quotation I missed, and as I state in the post "...half to benefit my understanding of how dynamic SQL can be developed" to connote my introduction to the concept. Thanks to both answer writers below for taking the time to point that out; I hesitantly apologise for asking a question not worthy of a dynamic-sql tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...few `'` were missing in your query

```
DECLARE @Focus VARCHAR(10);
SET @Focus = 'Completed'; /* User input event focus {Started, Completed} */

DECLARE @temp VARCHAR(500);
IF(@Focus = 'Completed')
SET @temp = '[Event End Date]'
ELSE
SET @temp = '[Event Start Date]'

DECLARE @PeriodStartDate DATE, @PeriodEndDate DATE;
SET @PeriodStartDate = '04/01/2014';
SET @PeriodEndDate = GETDATE();
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX);
SET @sql = 
        'SELECT ' +
        'CASE DATEPART(M, ' + @temp  + ')' +
        ' WHEN 1 THEN ''January'' ' +
        ' WHEN 2 THEN ''February'' ' +
        ' WHEN 3 THEN ''March'' ' + 
        ' WHEN 4 THEN ''April'' ' +
        ' WHEN 5 THEN ''May'' ' +
        ' WHEN 6 THEN ''June'' ' +
        ' WHEN 7 THEN ''July'' ' +
        ' WHEN 8 THEN ''August'' ' +
        ' WHEN 9 THEN ''September'' ' +
        ' WHEN 10 THEN ''October'' ' +
        ' WHEN 11 THEN ''November'' ' +
        ' WHEN 12 THEN ''December'' ' +
        ' END AS [Event ' + @Focus + ' Month], ' +
        ' COUNT([Unique ID]) AS [Number of Events] ' +
        ' FROM [udf_Events](''' + @Focus + ''', ''' + CAST(@PeriodStartDate AS VARCHAR) + ''', ''' + CAST(@PeriodEndDate AS VARCHAR) + ''') ' +
        ' GROUP BY ' +
        ' DATEPART(M, ' + @temp + ')' +
        ' ORDER BY ' +
        ' DATEPART(M, ' + @temp + ')';                   

print    @sql
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not quoting the dates in the call to `udf_Events` so you end up with

```
[udf_Events](Completed, 2014-04-01, 2014-09-19)
```

instead of

```
[udf_Events](Completed, '2014-04-01', '2014-09-19')
```

The fix is to change the line

```
' FROM [udf_Events](' + @Focus + ', ' + CAST(@PeriodStartDate AS VARCHAR) + ', ' + CAST(@PeriodEndDate AS VARCHAR) + ') ' +
```

to

```
' FROM [udf_Events](' + @Focus + ', ''' + CAST(@PeriodStartDate AS VARCHAR) + ''', ''' + CAST(@PeriodEndDate AS VARCHAR) + ''') ' +
```

That said, if the parameters to `udf_Events` are `datetimes` then I would consider changing the format to `YYYYMMDD` as this is unambiguous. To do this you can use `CONVERT(char(8), <date>, 112)` where `<date>` is the date to be converted.

i.e:

```
' FROM [udf_Events](' + @Focus + ', ''' + CONVERT(char(8), @PeriodStartDate, 112) + ''', ''' + CONVERT(char(8), @PeriodEndDate, 112) + ''') ' +
```